# When using ADF Data Flow Data Preview I am seeing some errors on some specific rows. How do I find out the reason?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data flow in ADF. If I use the Data Flow Debug and Data preview at a particular step I can see of the 100 rows debugged 5 have errored. However, I cannot find out how to see the error detail.

[image: row level error]

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

**Update** My goal is to understand what caused the error so I can rectify it.

Comment: Do you want to separate the error rows? Or Do you want to find out which column resulted in error? Can you explain the requirements?

Comment: Thanks @Aswin. I want to know what caused the error so I can rectify the problem.

Comment: Hi baynezy, it depends on the activity & expressions you use in the activity. If it is an assert activity, check the expressions used. For instance, there can be a rule or expression that checks if  IngBakery column is not equal to Seasonal, then while data preview, you will see error mark. This mentions that, the assert expression is not evaluated to true. So, would be better if you take a look at expressions used on the activity you are doing a data preview. Or pls post screenshot for us to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **Cast transformation**, the error in the rows is due to data in that column are not being compatible to the other type. When data is not compatible while doing cast trnasformation, the transformed data will be `Null`. We can find the reason for the error from the null data itself. Below is the approach to do this.

- Split the error rows using **conditional split** transformation with the condition `isError()`. When the condition is true, the data will be part of `invalid`  stream. Otherwise, it will be in `valid` stream.
  [image]
- Add **derived column** transformation and create a new column named `error description`.
- You can give expression like `case(isNull(class), 'Error in casting the column **CLASS** to integer', isNull(mark), ' Error in casting the column **Mark** to integer')`. This will check if the class column data is null and error message will have the corresponding value. Otherwise, it checks for the mark column value and assign the corresponding value to that column.

[image]